# How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?

Tags: c++, plugins, cmake

I'm currently constructing a project with a plugin structure. I'm using CMake to compile the project. The plugins are compiled in separate directories. My problem is that CMake compiles and saves the binaries and plugins, dynamic libraries, in the directory structure of the source. How do I make CMake save the files in something like a *./bin* directory?

Comment: You should not override CMake's build directory layout.  Instead, use the [install()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command and `cmake --install`.  It will automatically copy executables to a `bin` subdirectory by default.

Comment: @alexchandel lol -- this was 11 year ago :) I love that you found it, and if thats true, it's a great answer :)

Answer (score 425, accepted):

As in Oleg's answer, I believe the correct variable to set is [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html). We use the following in our root CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

You can also specify the output directories on a per-target basis:

```
set_target_properties( targets...
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
```

In both cases you can append `_[CONFIG]` to the variable/property name to make the output directory apply to a specific configuration (the standard values for configuration are `DEBUG`, `RELEASE`, `MINSIZEREL` and `RELWITHDEBINFO`).

Comment: You can also override this on a per-target basis by setting the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY target property. See documentation here: http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Comment: DLRdave's link is dead. Try http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Comment: How to make it apply to all configurations at once?

Comment: The first three commands should apply to all configurations (specifically setting CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY). You would only set CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG (for example) if you wanted a different directory for debug output. The exact behaviour depends on the generator/toolchain you are using (for example Visual Studio project files include all configurations in one build tree, whilst the makefile generator will only generate makefiles for one build configuration).

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, considering that the command `install(TARGETS <target_name>)` still complains about "given no RUNTIME DESTINATION for executable target"? This variable supposedly provides a default value, therefore the `install` command should not complain about the absence of a `RUNTIME DESTINATION`.

Comment: `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` sets where static (archive) libraries (.a files on Linux) will be built. It doesn't affect where `install` puts files.

Comment: The problem is CMake isn't consistent. For example, `dll` is considered `RUN_TIME_OUTPUT` for CMake. Is there a list which says what is what in CMake?

Comment: @Royi everything is documented. If we learned anything at all about programming, is that Windows is always a [special](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#runtime-output-artifacts) child. I assume that's because `dll` in general are bundled together and there's no set way to just "install to the system" unlike on proper OS'es and so CMake devs decided to not bother separating them, as there's almost never a reason to do that.

Comment: take notice, you should put CMAKE_*** directives before adding the targets.

Answer (score 40):

Use `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/some/full/path/to/bin")`

Comment: Use the full path name to the directory as the variable value, and do not put a trailing "/" in the value... as in Adam Bowen's answer.

Comment: Why do you need to add the full path? It seems like an annoyance when you move your project...

Comment: maybe change the path "/some/full/path/to/bin" to something relative to the root CMakeLists.txt which will have its path set in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}

Comment: Does exactly what I want. You might want to use some variable like `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/some/path` or `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/some/path.`

Answer (score 9):

Use the `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` CMake variable to set the needed path. For details, refer to the online CMake documentation:

*[CMake 2.8.8 Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html)*

Answer (score 7):

As to me I am using cmake 3.5, the below(`set variable`) does not work:

```
set(
      ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/xy/cmake_practice/lib/"
      LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/xy/cmake_practice/lib/"
      RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/xy/cmake_practice/bin/"
)
```

but this works(`set set_target_properties`):

```
set_target_properties(demo5
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/xy/cmake_practice/lib/"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/xy/cmake_practice/lib/"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/home/xy/cmake_practice/bin/"
)
```

Comment: I am using Adam's answer with set (CMAKE_... and it works, but only when you do it before adding libraries, executables etc. I think it's an important note for beginners like me.

Comment: Wow. @ashrasmun saved me from going insane after a few hours. Absolutely nothing was working until coming to the realization that the order of these commands is very relevant.

Comment: CMake version 3.19, this worked: set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "/some/full/path/to/bin"). Also you can specify path relative to the current directory (directory from which the cmake command is being executed).

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
project (hello)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "bin")
add_executable (hello hello.c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this line config:

`set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/)`
place your any CMakeLists.txt project.

This `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` is your current source directory where project place .
and if wander why is `${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}`    check this file `CMakeCache.txt` then search the key word `output path`, all the variables define here, it would give a full explanation of  the project all setting.

Comment: This will force the executable to be build in the project working directory, which is counter to what the OP is trying to do. It's generally a bad idea. (What if you want to build two different configurations?) Also, `EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH` is superseded by `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`.

Answer (score 2):

To add on to this:

If you're using CMAKE to generate a *Visual Studio* solution, and you want *Visual Studio* to output compiled files into /bin, Peter's answer needs to be modified a bit:

```
# set output directories for all builds (Debug, Release, etc.)
foreach( OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES} )
    string( TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG )
    set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
    set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
    set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin )
endforeach( OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES )
```

Answer (score 2):

One more refinement to [serg06's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58988164/1416230):

To force the three paths to be used as-is with all generators and for all build configurations, you can add an empty generator expression as in the following:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "$<0:>${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin") # .exe and .dll
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "$<0:>${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib") # .so and .dylib
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "$<0:>${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib") # .lib and .a
```

That has the side-effect of forcing the Visual Studio generator in particular to use the specified path as-is, instead of appending a configuration-specific subdirectory, with no need for a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about changing the `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` like the answers above describe. It's not an ideal solution since it can make your CMake project [less friendly to add_subdirectory users](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/1451).

> I'm currently constructing a project with a plugin structure. I'm using CMake to compile the project. The plugins are compiled in separate directories. My problem is that CMake compiles and saves the binaries and plugins, dynamic libraries, in the directory structure of the source.

Sounds like your real issue is trying to load dlls.

CMake 3.21 added functionality for this exact situation.

`$<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:tgt> New in version 3.21.`

This generator expression can be used to copy all of the DLLs that a target depends on into its output directory in a POST_BUILD custom command using the cmake -E copy -t command. For example:

```
find_package(foo CONFIG REQUIRED) # package generated by install(EXPORT)

add_executable(exe main.c)
target_link_libraries(exe PRIVATE foo::foo foo::bar)
add_custom_command(TARGET exe POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy -t $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:exe> $<TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS:exe>
    COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS
)
```

Link to official documentation:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_RUNTIME_DLLS

Fundamentally this is a Windows issue CMake tries to provide a nice solution for since the MSVC compiler doesn't have `RPATH` support. Which makes this a trivial problem on almost all systems except for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat CMakeLists.txt
project (hello)
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR "/bin")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
add_executable (hello hello.c)
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer?