# How to tell CMake where to put build files?

Tags: linux, cmake

I want to tell CMake to output files and folders to a different folder instead of the current folder. I'm talking about the generated files by CMake below:

- file: CMakeCache.txt
- dir: CMakeFiles/
- file: Makefile
- dir: bin/
- file: cmake_install.cmake

Is there a way to let CMake output these files and folders in another folder?
I wrote a tool that executes CMake from the root of the project-directory, as a result my project-directory gets messed up with the generated files and folders listed above.

Here a link what I want:
http://pastebin.com/cxykCi5M

Hope this will clarify more what I want.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826789/cmake-output-build-directory) post may be of some assistance.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use the undocumented command line options `-B` and `-H` to specify your build directory and source directory respectively.  So, from your project's root, you can do:

```
cmake -Bbuild -H.
```

(Where build is your build directory path.)

Comment: @Fraser is it possible to specify the build folder as an option in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: @SteveLorimer - No, I'm afraid not.  It's pretty much up to the user, although there are some tricks to mitigate against users trying to do an in-source build for example if that's what you're really after.

Comment: Thank you for this hint... this helps me ... no "md XX;cd XX;cmake .." anymore ;)  thank you ;)

Comment: if they are undocumented, are they safe to use?

Comment: `-B` is documented, at least in CMake 3.14: `-B <path-to-build>           = Explicitly specify a build directory.` Of course you can display it with `cmake --help`

Comment: As of CMake 3.13, the `-B` is now documented. They also claim to use `-S` when providing the source directory, although the still undocumented `-H` option works also.