# CMake output to build directory

Tags: c++, cmake, build

In a CLI, we can do:

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -Bbuild -S./directory
```

But how can I output build files using CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: What do you mean by "output build files"? If you want to construct path under build directory, then `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` denotes path of the build directory.

Comment: Are you asking how can we output the list of build files generated by CMake?

Comment: @kiner_shah yes but in a sub directory

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the question. Could you add to the question post some (pseudo-)code with explanations what it is intended to do?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes ```${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}``` is the path location of your CMakeLists.txt. But I want cmake to create a directory "build" and generate all the output files into that directory. Is there any way you can write that in CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: No, you cannot adjust build directory inside `CMakeLists.txt`. See [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834596/specifying-build-directory-within-cmakelists-file) for more info.