# How to set up a CMake project correctly?

Tags: c++, cmake

While it's easy to find surface level information on how to use CMake, information how to actually use CMake properly seems to be extremely hard to find. How should in a decently sized CMake project (one executable, one or more static libraries used by that executable, one or more external dependencies used by the static libraries) the folders and CMakeList.txt files be ordered? What CMakeList.txt files should have what commands?

Comment: Have you read the Wiki http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake on cmake site?

Comment: @SergeiNikulov Citation: `You are now on the CMake wiki. 
Many pages are now DEPRECATED and sometimes even considered bad practice. Those are only kept as reference for previous CMake versions.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to learn how to use CMake effectively is by looking at other projects. [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) and its subprojects are a good example.

Generally, good coding practices convert to good CMake practices; you want modularity, a clear style and flexibility.

An example of this might be to have rules for building your executable inside the `src` directory, then use that target in the root project folder. Something like this:

```
-my_proj
|
----CMakeLists.txt //contains directives for top-level dependencies and linking, includes subfolders
----src
    |
    ----CMakeLists.txt //contains definition of your main executable target
    ----internal_lib
        |
        ----CMakeLists.txt //contains definition of your internal static libraries
```

my_proj/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(src)
find_package (Threads REQUIRED) #find pthreads package
target_link_libraries (my_exe my_lib ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}) #link against pthreads and my_lib
```

my_proj/src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(internal_lib)
add_executable(my_exe my_source1.cpp mysource2.cpp)
```

my_proj/src/internal_lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(my_lib my_lib_source1.cpp my_lib_source2.cpp)
```

Comment: Could you include a very simple example on what these CMakeLists.txt files would look like?

Comment: @ruslo, a fair point, but they are fairly well commented and show the usage of a broad range of features, which is more than I could say for many other examples. Additionally the CMakeLists  become simpler as you descend the directory structure; I would hope that anyone could understand the files for building internal static libraries, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this tutorial](http://mirkokiefer.com/blog/2013/03/cmake-by-example/) is exactly what you need to starting with a CMake configuration for a simple project including one executable and several libraries - take a look! I find the CMake by Example anyway the best possibility to learn CMake the easy way:

> **Using CMake with executables**
>
> ```
> add_executable(myapp main.c)
> ```
>
> **Using CMake with static libraries**
>
> ```
> add_library(test STATIC test.c)
> ```
>
> **Using CMake with dynamic libraries**
>
> ```
> add_library(test SHARED test.c)
> ```
>
> **Linking libraries to executables with CMake**
>
> ```
> add_subdirectory(libtest_project) 
>
> add_executable(myapp main.c)
>
> target_link_libraries(myapp test)
> ```

Comment: If you're interested you can improve this tutorial a little bit, use: [cmake -H. -B_builds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20611964/2288008) to build project (instead of `mkdir _builds && cd _builds && cmake ..`). `make` and `make install` will work for makefile only, you can use `cmake --build _builds` and `cmake --build _builds --target install` for any kind of generators. Also when you use `ExternalProject_Add` like that you can't use `find_package` modules.