# What is the difference between CMake's -S and -H option?

Tags: cmake

I searched a long time for a way of changing CMake's build directory without `cd`ing into it.

I eventually find the `-H` option and make my scripts with it.
Now I typed in `cmake --help` and I directly have seen following output:

```
$ cmake --help
Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
  cmake [options] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>
```

I recently use:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.14.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

and I think in older version this was missing.

Nevertheless, I wonder if there is any difference between `-H` and `-S` option. Furthermore I wonder if they are safe to use at all. I found this questions in other posts, but it has not been answered (e.g. here: [How to tell CMake where to put build files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610255/how-to-tell-cmake-where-to-put-build-files))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-H` option is not documented and exists long before `-S` option. It was somewhat considered a "trick" before `-S` option existed. The `-H` option purpouse was to make developers life easier, but they left it in release builds, so people started using it. Since cmake 3.13 (I think it's Novemeber 2018) the `-S` option is available, making `-H` obsolete (or not? I don't know what the intention of cmake developers is).

Seeing [cmake sources](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L981) the `-H` and `-S` option act exactly the same.