# Specifying temporary build files path on cmake3

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I am using cmake3 (version 3.6.1) on Centos. In the previous versions of CMake, I was able to specify the build directory using the `-B` option:

```
cmake -GNinja -B build
```

With that, all the temporary files such as `CMakeCache.txt` are stored in the build folder. Now with the cmake3, I don't see the `-B` option anymore. Is there a different option?

Comment: `(cd build && cmake -Gninja ..)`? - but I don't think -B was removed

Comment: Browsing versions in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/manual/cmake.1.html seems to suggest that versions prior to 3.13 did not have that option, but more recent ones do.

Comment: Missing in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake.1.html

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake.1.html#synopsis) for the CMake 3.6.X command line options, the `-B` option is indeed not listed:

> ```
> cmake [<options>] (<path-to-source> | <path-to-existing-build>)
> ```

However, the functionality is still there. You can still use `-B` to specify a location for the build directory (the current directory is the default). This option, along with `-H` for specifying the **source directory**, were two *undocumented* command line options for many CMake releases (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20611964/3987854) answer).

Because the functionality to support the `-B` option was retained, and is still commonly used, CMake added it back into their documentation in CMake 3.13. The latest [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#generate-a-project-buildsystem) describes the `-B` behavior that has been present all along:

> ```
> cmake [<options>] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>
> ```
>
> Uses `<path-to-build>` as the build tree and `<path-to-source>` as the source tree. The specified paths may be absolute or relative to the current working directory. The source tree must contain a `CMakeLists.txt` file. The build tree will be created automatically if it does not already exist. For example:
>
> ```
>      $ cmake -S src -B build
> ```

Comment: I am stuck on 3.6.1. If I try your suggestion i.e., -S src -B build. I get this error

build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @ssk I expanded my answer. The `-S` option to specify the source directory is new, but the undocumented option `-H` also allows you to specify the source directory. This option `-H` should be available in CMake 3.6, and is actually still available in the latest version of CMake (3.16) today.