# After an in-source build, how to force CMake to build someplace else?

Tags: cmake, directory-structure, building

Suppose I have a project named `foo`, with sources under `/foo/src`. Also suppose that at some point in the past, someone ran `cmake /foo/src`, so there are build files there.

Now, I want to perform a build of `foo`, in `/foo/build`. But if I `cd /foo/build; cmake /foo/src` - it treats `/foo/src` as the build directory, and configures and generates that build files there rather than in the current directory.

Questions:

1. What is the minimal set of files in `/foo/src` to delete in order for cmake to configure and generate build files in `/foo/build`?
2. Can I force cmake to use `/foo/build` without deleting anything from `/foo/src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. A sufficient set of files to delete

A sufficient, though perhaps not minimal, set of files to delete:

```
CMakeCache.txt
Makefile
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeFiles/
```

and if you also have tests enabled, then

```
CTestTestfile.cmake
Testing/
tests/CTestTestfile.cmake
tests/Makefile
tests/cmake_install.cmake
tests/CMakeFiles/
```

### 2. How to force a different build location without deletions:

If you execute

```
cmake -B /foo/build -S /foo/src
```

(for non-ancient versions of CMake), CMake will ignore the previous build and build under `/foo/build`. You don't need it to be your current working directory when issuing this command.

<sub>The second part of this answer can actually be found within [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24435795/1593077)</sub>

Comment: If you are Using Git, then you could just do git clean -fd to remove untracked files generated by previous configure/build.

Comment: @sanjivgupta: 1. I may not be  using git. 2. Some of the generated files may be covered by `.gitignore`.

Comment: @einpklum agree. git clean -fd may not do a full job always. It just worked for me, so just wanted to mention that it may save time for someone. But it's good to know anyways what files were generated by cmake , so it's good that you mentioned them in the first place.