# Cmake build directory

Tags: cmake

After running cmake/make for my own project, I noticed cmake puts object files into a directory named `CMakeFiles/myproject.dir/`. How can I set a different build directory (e.g. `bin/)`? I know of the variables `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` or `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`, but they are supposed to be read-only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir

Answer (score 1):

As you already note, you [can't set](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-November/033508.html) `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variable.

Depending on your purposes you can use:

[install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3ainstall)

```
add_executable(simple_bin ${SOURCES})
install(TARGETS simple_bin DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

[add_test](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_test)

```
add_executable(simple_bin ${SOURCES})
enable_testing()
add_test(test_name simple_bin --data-directory ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

Comment: This will put the executable file into `bin`directory. But what about the object files? They still are put into `CMakeFiles/myproject.dir`

Comment: Well, I was interested in having my own directory layout... and out of curiosity. But it seems it is not very convenient and not so easy to achieve. Thanks!