# Basic Cmake and make on Mac OS Maverick for C

Tags: c, macos, makefile, cmake

I'm a complete beginner in using Cmake to compile my own C code and I'm running Mac OS X Mavericks.

My problem is as follow. For my intro to Cmake,  created a folder containing the following folders

```
bin/
build/
src/
   fonctions.h
   fonctions.c
   main.c
```

Here my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project(Addition)
add_executable(
    bin/addition
    src/main.c
    src/fonctions.h
    src/fonctions.c
)
```

When I run:

```
$ cmake . -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

and then make from my root folder, no problem.

But when I run:

```
$ cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

and then make from my /build folder I got this error message:

```
Linking C executable bin/addition
ld: can't open output file for writing: bin/addition, errno=2 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/addition] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bin/addition.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `bin/` from your [add_executable](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_executable) and use [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir) to change your build location

```
add_executable(
    addition
    src/main.c
    src/fonctions.h
    src/fonctions.c
)
```