# Parent CMakeLists.txt overwriting child CMakeLists.txt output directory options

Tags: unix, cmake, cross-platform

I am trying to place a library from a project into a certain directory in my build output, but the parent CMakeLists.txt is overwriting the output settings.
The parent CMakeLists.txt sets all libraries to be placed in a /lib directory.

One of my libraries, however, needs to be placed into a /python library. The settings I have work on Windows. Meaning, all libs excluding my python specific library get placed in a /lib folder, and the python lib gets placed into the /python folder.

The problem appears when I build on Linux. All of the libraries, including the python specific library, get placed into the /lib folder. The FORCE option does nothing.

If I were only building for one platform, I could deal with either directory layout. But I really want to preserve the same layout across platforms.

CMakeLists.txt as follows:

-Parent CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(renderer2d)

#enable debug symbols by default
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
endif()
#(you can also set on cl: -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)

#place outside of Debug/Release folders
SET(OUTPUT_BINDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_BINDIR})

SET(OUTPUT_LIBDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_LIBDIR})

SET (CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
SET (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
IF(WIN32)
  SET (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ELSE(WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ENDIF(WIN32)

# For each configuration (Debug, Release, MinSizeRel... and/or anything the user chooses)
FOREACH(CONF ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
# Go uppercase (DEBUG, RELEASE...)
STRING(TOUPPER "${CONF}" CONF)
SET("CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
SET("CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
IF(WIN32)
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
ELSE()
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

#set the source directory
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)

add_subdirectory(shape)
add_subdirectory(py_shape)
add_subdirectory(scripts)

#define sources and executable
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "renderer2d")
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})

#find python
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#detect and add SFML
#this line checks a cmake file for hints on where to find cmake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
#find any version 2.x of SFML
#see the FindSFML.cmake file for additional details and instructions
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

#find and include Boost python libraries
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

#link all found libraries to the executable
if(WIN32)
    target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<BOOL:${MSVC}>:BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB>)
endif(WIN32)

target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} shape)
```

-Child CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(py_shape CXX)

#set file variables
file(GLOB SOURCE src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB HEADERS inc/*.hpp)

#place outside of Debug/Release folders
SET(OUTPUT_BINDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/python)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_BINDIR})

set(OUTPUT_LIBDIR ${CMAKEK_BINARY_DIR}/python)
MAKE_DIRECTORY(${OUTPUT_LIBDIR})

SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH  "build directory")
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH  "build directory")
IF(WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_BINDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ELSE(WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${OUTPUT_LIBDIR} CACHE PATH "build directory")
ENDIF(WIN32)

#for each configuration
FOREACH(CONF ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
#Go uppercase {DEBUG, RELEASE...)
SET("CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
SET("CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
IF(WIN32)
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_BINDIR}")
ELSE()
  SET("CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONF}" "${OUTPUT_LIBDIR}")
ENDIF()
ENDFOREACH()

#find packages
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

#build the library
add_library(python_shape MODULE ${SOURCE})
#enable C++11 if available
target_compile_features(python_shape PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
#link library
target_link_libraries(python_shape shape ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
#drop "lib" from the library name
set_target_properties(python_shape PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

if(WIN32)
  #set extension to ".pyd"
  set_target_properties(python_shape PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".pyd")
endif(WIN32)
```

Comment: The variables - like `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` - you are changing are global variables. Those values are not applied to all targets while parsing, but at the end of the main `CMakeLists.txt` (end of configuration step, 1st) are taken to be applied to all targets as the default values (during make environment generation step, 2nd). And `add_subdirectory()` opens up its own variable scope, so changes there to global variables won't help. And changing the cached values in the child `CMakeLists.txt` won't overwrite the "normal" variables set in the parent `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: See [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables/31044116) for more details. So set/change all global values in the cache with `FORCE` (in the parent and child `CMakeLists.txt`) or - preferable according to you description - only change/overwrite the corresponding `python_shape` target properties like [`ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) (overwriting your defaults set in the parent `CMakeLists.txt` only for `python_shape`).

Comment: @Florian I was really trying to solve this without having to come back and bother you, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've tried setting 'LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY' in my child 'CMakeLists.txt', but it doesn't do anything. 'The python_shape' still gets placed into the /lib directory. I'm really at a standstill in this project because of this problem, so if you have anymore advice I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've done some debugging with your code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

I successfully tested the following with MinGW and CMake 3.3.0 (I reduced your example a little to concentrate on the output directories):

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(renderer2d C CXX)

# TODO: Remove, this is just for testing
file(WRITE "src/renderer2d.cpp" "int main(void) {}") 
file(WRITE "py_shape/src/py_shape.cpp" "") 

#enable debug symbols by default
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "")
  set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
endif()
#(you can also set on cl: -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)

#place outside of Debug/Release folders
#see http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
if(WIN32)
  set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}")
else()
  set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
endif()

#see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake
if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.1")
  if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=gnu++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
  endif()
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif()

#set the source directory
file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.cpp)

add_subdirectory(py_shape)

#define sources and executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} python_shape)
```

**py_shape/CMakeLists.txt**

```
#set file variables
file(GLOB SOURCE src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB HEADERS inc/*.hpp)

#build the library
add_library(python_shape MODULE ${SOURCE})

set_target_properties(python_shape PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/python")

#drop "lib" from the library name
set_target_properties(python_shape PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

if(WIN32)
  #set extension to ".pyd"
  set_target_properties(python_shape PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".pyd")
endif()
```

Now `python_shape.pyd` is created in `python` subdirectory.

What I have changed/removed:

- Setting the `..._OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` global variables in the child `CMakeLists.txt` is not necessary and/or won't work
- Added [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) to overwrite the output directory for `python_shape` `MODULE` library target (see also e.g. [Custom Directory for CMake Library Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742090/custom-directory-for-cmake-library-output))
- Removed the "by config" settings, because I think it's a feature that multi-configuration make environments like Visual Studio put different configuration binaries into equally named sub-folders.
- Added some `if` statements around `-std=c++11`. It has also only to be set once in the main `CMakeLists.txt`
- You don't need to create the output directories "manually", they are created automatically by the make environments

For the reasoning why your first approach didn't work, see my comments above.

And I wouldn't recommend the use of [`file(GLOB ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) to collect source files (see e.g. [Why is cmake file GLOB evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil) or [CMake/Ninja attempting to compile deleted `.cpp` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949452/cmake-ninja-attempting-to-compile-deleted-cpp-file)).

**Alternatives**

As with all languages/frameworks like `CMake` there is more then one way to do things.

E.g. you could also use `POST_BUILD` steps to copy your binaries to a common output directory:

- see [Cmake: use add_custom_command to copy binary to specific location failed when location doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120511/cmake-use-add-custom-command-to-copy-binary-to-specific-location-failed-when-lo)
- and - a little more up-to-date utilizing "generator expressions" - [CMake: how to specify different steps for different build configurations for Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357235/cmake-how-to-specify-different-steps-for-different-build-configurations-for-vis)