# why CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY doesn't work?

Tags: cmake

I want to build the static library on a `bin` subdir, but cmake seems not not doing what I want.
Here is the Cmake file I wrote.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(FancyLogger)

set(SOURCE_FILES FancyLogger.cpp)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_library(FancyLogger STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I made a `build` subdir, and ran `cmake ..` and `make` in this sub directory, hoping that the output static library will be generated on the bin library.

But the output remains in the `build` directory, Why?

Here is my file tree

=====
|

| FancyLogger.cpp

| CMakeLists.txt

| /build

| /bin

Comment: The practice is to *install* static libs in the lib dir, not the bin dir.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For static libraries you have to set the [`CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), not the [`CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).

So you will have:

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

See [how do I make cmake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir/6595001#6595001)

By the way, it's probably not a good idea to create subfolders within the source directory, especially in an automated way.

Comment: I agree. You should use ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin or ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin instead

Comment: @DimitriMerejkowsky why is that not a good idea. Your saying the following is bad? set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib).

Comment: Yes. For instance, if you want to compile for linux and cross-compile for android, you can have a `build/linux` and a `build/android` folder, and thus your library should be in `bulid/linux/lib` or `build/android/lib` so you don't mix binaries built for different operating systems in the same directory.