# CMake output directory by platform

Tags: c++, cmake, multiplatform

I would like to output my library into different folder based on the platform/compiler/architecture/configuration, so it should look like this :

**platform(arch)-compiler(version)-configuration**

A few examples would be:

```
win32-vc12.0-debug
win32-vc12.0-release
win64-vc14.0-debug
win64-vc14.0-release

unix-gcc6.1-debug
unix-gcc6.1-release
unix-clang3.8-debug
unix-clang3.8-release
```

I actually have no idea how to generate those, could anyone guide me ?
Thank you

Comment: Just create these output directories and compile your sources inside.

Comment: But how to do it with CMake ? I only need the output (.lib/.a) in those folder, nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to [set the bin directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir) for the project:

```
math(EXPR platform_bits "${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} * 8")
set(platform_dir ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}${platform_bits}-${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION})

foreach(config DEBUG RELEASE RELWITHDEBINFO MINSIZEREL)

    foreach(var CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config} CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config} CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${config})
        set(${var} "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${platform_dir}-${config}")
        string(TOLOWER "${${var}}" ${var})
    endforeach()

endforeach()
```

This won't give you the exact directory names you are looking for, but is a good start. You can look at the [CMake variables list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) for a list of platform specific configuration information. You would then need to apply some logic that will transform the CMake defined values into the specific ones you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, this is very great ! I thank you very much, it works very great

Comment: I didn't have CMake installed on my laptop, so I hadn't checked the syntax and there were a couple of small mistakes - I've fixed them now!