# Copying of latest DLL is always one build-step behind with CMake 3.6.2 and MSVS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cmake

I have a simple project with the following directory structure.

```
HelloCMake (directory)
|--CMakeLists.txt
|--main.cpp
|
|--HelloDll (directory)
   |--CMakeLists.txt
   |--hw1.hpp
   |--hw1.cpp
```

The intent is to create a DLL out of `hw1.cpp` and call one of its functions from `main.cpp`, both functions printing their `hello world (main or dll)` respectively. `HelloCMake\CMakeLists.txt` has:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project (HelloDll)
add_subdirectory (HelloDll)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
# the above facilitates running / debugging the program from VS without install

add_executable (hw1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (hw1 hw1Dll)
```

Now `HelloDll\CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library (hw1Dll SHARED hw1.cpp hw1.hpp)
set_target_properties (hw1Dll PROPERTIES WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)
```

Let's say I modify `hw1.cpp` to print `from 2 dll hello world` and build, and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program, it prints `from 1 dll hello world`, the previous version. I can see that the latest dll was not copied. If I perform another build, it copies the latest dll and I see the right output.

I have tried solutions from other posts to no avail. The current one is from [how do I make cmake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir). What am I missing? I am sure it's something embarrassingly simple. Thanks.

Comment: I solve this by using a common bin folder where all executables / dlls for a CMake generated project are located. This is /bin relative to the root CMakeLists.txt. And yes this is under Visual Studio. So there is no need to copy the dlls since they share the same output folder as the executables that are generated for the whole project.

Comment: ***What am I missing?*** Do that only in the root CMakeLists.txt. and make sure that the other CMakeLists.txt files do not have a `project()` in them.

Comment: You set *CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY* **after** processing directory with library, so the variable doesn't affect the library.

Comment: Good point. I set `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` in the root CMakeLists.txt before any add_subdirectory() commands.

Comment: Thanks for the quick diagnosis of the problem `@Tsyvarev`, now it works.