# CMake add_executable in another directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I am making a bunch of tests in order to verify that each library are correctly linked, and then some tests for the functionalities of my code.

I would like to have X different executable in the directory project/build/tests
and I want my program to be build in project/build

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(ProjectName)
# Linking library ...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST} ${INCLUDE_LIST})
```

until here, everything is fine and works as wanted but then I don't know how to tell cmake to create my tests in another directory as this does not work

```
add_executable(tests/OpenMP_Check tests/openmp.cpp)
```

my project has this architecture :

project :

- src
- include
- lib
- build
- - tests
- tests

To put it in a nutshell : How do I ask CMake to create my tests in another directory ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) on your test executable to set its `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` to just `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to arrowd I managed to do it with these lines

```
add_executable(OpenMP_Check tests/openmp.cpp)
set_target_properties(OpenMP_Check PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tests")
```

After looking for the way to use "set_target_properties" (and the doc of CMake is honestly unreadable) I found this thread, which makes this question a duplicate.
[how do I make cmake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir)