# cmake move build files in a subdirectory after configuring and building

Tags: cmake

I am very new in cmake. I am trying to build a simple test project. This is my directory tree.

```
testproj
   |---CMakeLists.txt
   |
   |---build (directory)
   |
   |---bin (directory)
   |
   |---include
   |   |---add.h
   |
   |---lib
   |   |---add.cxx
   |
   |---test
   |   |---main.cxx
```

After configuring and building, I want the static library *.a and the binary executable to go into bin/ subdirectory. So currently, my CmakeLists.txt looks like this.

CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(testproj)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "bin/")
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH "bin/")

file(GLOB main_src "test/main.cxx")
file(GLOB lib_src "lib/*.cxx")

add_library(lib STATIC ${lib_src})
add_executable(main ${main_src})

target_link_libraries(main lib)
```

After building the project, the source directory looks like this.

```
testproj
   |---CMakeCache.txt
   |
   |---CMakeFiles (directory)
   |
   |---CMakeLists.txt
   |
   |---Makefile
   |
   |---bin
   |   |---liblib.a
   |   |---main
   |
   |---build (directory)
   |
   |---cmake_install.cmake
   |
   |---compile_commands.json
   |
   |---include
   |   |---add.h
   |
   |---lib
   |   |---add.cxx
   |
   |---test
   |   |---main.cxx
```

Library *.a and binary executable main went into the bin/ subdirectory as expected. But, I want the following files and directories to go into the build/ subdirectory everytime I build the project:

```
CMakeCache.txt, CMakeFiles, Makefile, cmake_install.cmake, compile_commands.json
```

How can I achieve this in CMakeLists.txt? I don't want to do

```
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

EDIT:
I configure from the testproj directory. I don't want to cd into the build/ subdirectory.

Comment: `After configuring and building` How do you configure?

Comment: Files like `CMakeCache.txt`, `CMakeFiles` are created in the directory which is specified as a **build** directory for CMake. Normally, this is the current directory, but it is possible to pass this directory as a parameter to `cmake`. Note that placing **output** files **outside** of the build directory is a bad practice. This is what you want to achieve by putting the library and the executable under `bin/` while building the project under `build/`. Instead you could **install** your files under any location. See what `install` CMake command does.

Comment: @Tsyvarev My question is already marked as duplicate and the given link doesn't answer my question. I would look into "install". How can I pass the current directory as a parameter in cmake? Shouldn't it be possible just to change into the build/ subdirectory and build the project in CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52024730/3440745) describes how to tell CMake to use particular directory (instead of the current one) as a build directory. The script `CMakeLists.txt` cannot affect on a build directory.