# EXE doesn't work correctly with DLL in CMake

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, clion

I've read a number of posts concerning similar issues but I still can't find the solution to the following problem.

I have two CLion (OS Windows) projects *mylib* and *myexe* which reside in separate directories at the same level. mylib consists of two files:
library.h

```
void hello();
```

and library.cpp

```
#include "library.h"
#include <iostream>

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt for *mylib* is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(mylib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(mylib SHARED library.cpp library.h)
```

Next, the project *myexe* consists of one file main.cpp

```
#include "../mylib/library.h"

int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

with the following CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(myexe)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(myexe main.cpp)

find_library(RESULT mylib "d:/src/test/mylib/cmake-build-debug")
target_link_libraries(myexe "${RESULT}")
```

Both projects are built without errors. But when I run *myexe*, the "Hello, world" isn't printed, and I'm getting the following:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Please help me, how to solve this issue and link DLL correctly.

Comment: This error means that you `myexe.exe` tries to load `mylib.dll` at start-up. Thus, it's linked correctly. Please, check whether `myexe.exe` and `mylib.dll` are built into the same directory (or copy `mylib.dll` into the folder of `myexe.exe` afterwards). Btw. In `CMake`, you can force that all binaries are built into the same output directory to prevent such issues in the future.

Comment: FYI: [SO: How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6595001/7478597)

Comment: FYI: [microsoft.com: 2.3.1 NTSTATUS Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) (Please, do a text search on this site for `135`. I couldn't find anything in the HTML code to link to it directly.)

Answer (score 1):

As @Scheff suggested, looking at [How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir/6595001#6595001), I just added theses three lines to the CMakeLists.txt files of both projects *myexe* and *mylib*:

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../../bin")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../../bin")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../../bin")
```

where "../../bin" is the desired directory to store .dll and .exe.

Comment: You should not override CMake's global build layout.  Instead, use the [install()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) command to copy files to a final location, or use a `POST_BUILD` custom command to copy DLLs next to the exe.