# Is there a way to change the path to save the Linker's output of a C/C++ program in CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, clion

So, I am starting out with CLion. And I have a project where I managed to store the `.cpp` and `.h` files in a folder under the working directory called `src`. However, I am unable to get the linker's generated output (the executable file) in a separate folder, let's say `bin` under the working directory.

For reference, the file structure of the project that I am seeking is:

- Working Directory

  - make-build-debug
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - src

    - example.cpp
    - example.h
  - bin

    - example (*example.out*)

**Platform Specification:**

1. OS: macOS 13.4.1
2. CLion Version: 2023.1.4

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(Password_Manager_CPP)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(.)

add_executable(Password_Manager_CPP
        src/PasswordManager.cpp src/PasswordDriver.cpp src/PasswordManager.h)
```

For example, if you have a file `example.cpp`, and you compile it using the command: `g++ example.cpp -o example`. I want the UNIX Exec file, `example`, to be stored in the bin folder.

I tried out some potential solutions on the internet. I looked into YouTube, Google, forums, and even StackOverflow. However, I could not find a solution that sufficed my needs.

Comment: "the compiler's generated output (the executable file) " - isn't that the linker's output? AFAIK, the compiler creates OBJ files and the linker creates the executable.

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` should work, unless CLion (or macos) somehow screws around with cmake's normal behaviour. If you're using a multi-config generator the binaries end up in a configuration-specific subdir (e.g. `bin/Debug`), but there are workarounds for that... If it's indeed CLion using a modified cmake version, you may be able to get the binaries to the desired location using `install()` commands + the cmake install step.

Comment: Btw: I strongly recommend not putting any build results into the source tree by default, since makes use of the source dir with multiple cmake configurations hard, if not impossible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir)

Comment: @ThomasWeller You are correct. My terminology wasn't right.

Comment: @fabian Hey, I am not looking for the build results specifically. Imagine you have `example.cpp`, and you run the command `g++ example.cpp -o example`. So, this command will generate an executable file called `example`. I want this file to be in the `bin` folder instead of the main working directory, as CLion is doing.

Comment: @starball I actually have looked into that post. And I tried out the solutions. However, none worked.

Comment: you're supposed to say that in your question post and give details about what you observed when you tried them rather than "it didn't work". Even better if you show exactly _how_ you tried them. Maybe you just did it wrong.

Comment: @starball I am learning more about using this platform. Thank you for your input. As I can see, quotations did the job for me. 

Thank you for putting the effort into helping me out. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after quite a bit of surfing through different documentation, and forums. I found a way that works for me.

> `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
```

Using this in your `CMakeLists.txt` puts the linker's output into your desired folder.

Helpful resources:

- [How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir)
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html

You can use the below-written code too.

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
```

One thing to notice here, the path is within a quotation, which I was not doing before.

I would advise the latter one, as within my understanding of CMake as of now, the variables used in the latter block of code supersedes the previous.