# CMake: run executable from outside script

Tags: cmake

So I have a bash script that builds my project with CMake and I want to run the program after the build.
The problem is that the executable name and path can change based on the CMakeLists.txt.
Is there a way to get the location of the executable of the last build from an external script? I don't want to hard-code it.

I tried searching online and looking at what IDEs do but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can grep the cmake output, but it'd be unreliable if the project builds multiple targets.

Comment: You could modify the cmake project to generate a text file containing the full file path to a given executable. I'm not sure though if you also need this to work when selecting the target to build via `cmake --build ... --target <target_name>`. Could you clarify whether this kind of solution would solve your problem? Also: Do you consider a target being built, if no built steps had to be taken to produce the binary (i.e. none of the source files/compiler+linker options changed and the target was fully linked already?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used `cmake --build --target help` to get all targets and grepped the name of the executable target. From that I can guess the path of the executable as long as I don't change it manually in the CMakeLists.txt. Not the best solution but it works well enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches:

- In your CMakeLists.txt file, write a custom target that [echoes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-echo) the value of [`$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_FILE) to a file (either you echo to a config-specific file (using `$<CONFIG>`), or you settle for a scenario where the file is overwritten for whichever config you last built that needed to update that target (not really a nice scenario, but simpler for your script))
- Just put your target files in a simpler location. See [How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6594796/11107541) (using [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), multi-config generators will still append a config-specific part to the path).