# How to change CMake's PYTHON_ADD_MODULE shared object's output

Tags: python, c++, cmake, boost

I have a small C++ library and I am writing some Python bindings using Boost and CMake. In my CMakeLists.txt I have the line

```
PYTHON_ADD_MODULE(${LIB_PY_PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_SOURCES})
```

where those variables are simply the name of the project and the list of .cpp files that I want to compile. This correctly generates an .so file which I can import from Python and use.

However I would like to move the .so file to another directory, is it possible to do that by changing the output path of the add_module command or by having some kind of copying/moving post-build step defined in CMake? Even if it's another subdirectory of the build folder?

I tried with file(RENAME ...), but that is executed when configuring the CMake project and not when building it.

Comment: you should be able to use output directory on either archive or library (not sure which on for your case). https://stackoverflow.com/a/6595001/2855875